# Quartz.Net embedded into Asp.NET MVC2, not firing off jobs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

I'm trying to get Quartz.net working by embedding into my .Net MVC2 application. I know this is not ideal, but I'm just trying to get it up and running before moving it over to a service. I can't get my jobs to fire off, but I think I'm configured correctly. In my Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Quartz.IScheduler scheduler = BuildQuartzScheduler();
    ... 
 }
```

And the method, taken straight from the tutorial:

```
private IScheduler BuildQuartzScheduler()
{
    // construct a scheduler factory
    ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

    // get a scheduler
    IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
    sched.Start();

    // construct job info
    JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("myJob", null, typeof(QuartzController));
    // fire every hour
    Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeMinutelyTrigger();
    // start on the next even hour
    trigger.StartTimeUtc = TriggerUtils.GetEvenMinuteDate(DateTime.UtcNow);
    trigger.Name = "myTrigger";
    sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
    return sched;
}
```

And the "controller:"

```
    public class QuartzController : IJob
    {
       public QuartzController() {
       }

       public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Nothing ever gets fired. What's going on? I'm sure there must be a simple syntax mistake, but it is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `Application_Start` looks like that, then I reckon your `scheduler` variable is likely to be garbage collected as soon as that method finishes executing.

I'd store a reference to the `scheduler` as a static variable in your `HttpApplication` class. This way, the reference hangs around for the duration of the process. A guess, but worth a shot.

Comment: it's actually the scheduler factory that needs to be kept as a static variable.

Comment: This is one of those answers that are so obvious we don't see it. as an addition, you don't need to set the job to a controller, you can even create a logic class and then call a method that inherits from the IJob interface. Quite useful stuff

Comment: @MarkoLahma - Why wouldn't it be the scheduler that needs to be kept as static?  Once the scheduler is created by the factory, it's the scheduler that needs to live on.  Subsequent calls to Quartz are done through the scheduler object, not the factory.  No?

Comment: Yes, you should probably have both as static application wide static variables. I usually prefer to have an IoC container that defines them as singletons.