# Mimic Windows Task Scheduler with code

Tags: c#, .net, scheduling

I'm looking for a way to make a program that runs itself (or a method) every X time (days, weeks, whatever). Basically, I want my program to do what the Windows Task Scheduler could do. The reason I don't use the Task Scheduler is because I plan to deploy this application on a server which I have no remote access to, but need to re-generate some files every given time.

Suggestions?

Comment: Using Windows Task Scheduler without remote access works just fine. Use local access as per normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Quarts.net:

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This looks like what I need, in conjunction with this other answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539995/quartz-net-embedded-into-asp-net-mvc2-not-firing-off-jobs

Answer (score 1):

You can just run a program as a service, it can have a `Timer` that is executed on the schedule you need. [Topshelf](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf) is a simple service host for .NET that could you generate that service. I think the sample service provided does just that at a small interval.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Windows Service and use a timer.  You can pick between System.Timers.Timer and System.Threading.Timer based on the differences you can find here:

http://www.intellitechture.com/System-Windows-Forms-Timer-vs-System-Threading-Timer-vs-System-Timers-Timer/