# Quartz.Net cron trigger C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, global-asax, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.NET for job scheduling in my ASP.NET application, and I have created one trigger in my `global.asax` file:

```
// Code that runs on application startup
ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
// get a scheduler
IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
sched.Start();
// construct job info
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("mySendMailJob", typeof(SendMailJob));

SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger("myTrigger",
                        null,
                        DateTime.UtcNow,
                        null,
                        SimpleTrigger.RepeatIndefinitely,
                        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

This code works fine for me and fires after every 1 minute and does my required work.

I tried to create another trigger in this way to fire at a specific time of the day like 10.00 AM, but it's not working for me. I also want to create misfire instructions. Suppose my trigger is not fired on specific time; how do I get misfire instructions to reload my trigger to do the job?

```
ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
// get a scheduler
IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
sched.Start();
// construct job info
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("mySendMailJob", typeof(SendMailJob));

Trigger trigger2 = TriggerUtils.MakeDailyTrigger(10, 00);

// schedule the job for execution
//trigger2.Name = "mySendMailTrigger";
sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger2);
```

Comment: If you have the chance to do the job in a windows service then better do that. There are risks when doing background tasks in ASP.NET. Read http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: Thanx Malcom For Your Suggestion,
But Thing is I M Working on ASP Application That will be hosted on Shared Server. And I Cant Host My Window Service There And I Want One Of My Routine Send An Emails To User On Specified Time On Daily Basis Or According To Defined Criteria. After Long Searching And Discussion I Found Quartz.Net Will Do My Desired Work. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cron trigger formula with [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/), simple as:

```
0 0 10 1/1 * ? *
```

And create a CronTrigger class to use it, see the [documentation](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_6.html), sorry, I don't have an example now, but if you can't do I'll post tomorrow.

Comment: Thanx Gustavo,
 I Have Done Somwthing With Cron Triggers But Sometimes It Missfired

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to store schedFact  in a static variable?

That solved the problem here:

[Quartz.Net embedded into Asp.NET MVC2, not firing off jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539995/quartz-net-embedded-into-asp-net-mvc2-not-firing-off-jobs)